# mySQL query combing column count()

Tags: mysql, count

I've been struggling for the past few hours of trying to combine two queries together to save myself some PHP code.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb47e0/2

Edit (bit more info!):

This is what the data looks like in my table.

```
account_id personnelofficer_no personnelofficer color
500079462  1                                    #000000
340345950  2                                    #555555
734356754                      1
972345435                      1
883243435                      2
```

I'm just trying to list all of the personnel officers with all of the members that have been assigned to them.

```
SELECT wot_clan_members.account_name, wot_info.color, total
FROM wot_info
JOIN wot_clan_members ON wot_clan_members.account_id = wot_info.account_id
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) total 
    FROM wot_info 
    WHERE wot_info.personnelofficer <> '' 
    GROUP BY wot_info.personnelofficer
) as total
WHERE wot_clan_members.role = 'personnel_officer'
```

Its currently outputting the following:

```
account_name     color   total
conan230160      #1E90FF 24
conan230160      #1E90FF 19
conan230160      #1E90FF 20
conan230160      #1E90FF 22
Woody_the_Viking #800080 24
Woody_the_Viking #800080 19
Woody_the_Viking #800080 20
Woody_the_Viking #800080 22
Aledius          #8B0000 24
Aledius          #8B0000 19
Aledius          #8B0000 20
Aledius          #8B0000 22
Smoothbore247    #228B22 24
Smoothbore247    #228B22 19
Smoothbore247    #228B22 20
Smoothbore247    #228B22 22
```

The desired output is:

```
conan230160      #1E90FF 24
Woody_the_Viking #800080 19
Aledius          #8B0000 20
Smoothbore247    #228B22 22
```

I don't know if someone could please point me in the right direction or explain how to do it?

Thanks very much.
Jason

Edit:

I don't know if I'm getting closer or not.

```
SELECT wot_clan_members.account_id, wot_clan_members.account_name,     wot_info.color, total
FROM wot_info

JOIN wot_clan_members
ON wot_clan_members.account_id = wot_info.account_id

JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM wot_info  WHERE wot_info.personnelofficer <> ''     GROUP BY wot_info.personnelofficer ) as total
ON wot_clan_members.account_id = wot_info.account_id

WHERE wot_clan_members.role = 'personnel_officer'
GROUP BY wot_clan_members.account_name
```

Outputs:

```
account_id  account_name     color   total
517440262   Aledius          #8B0000 24
508425497   conan230160      #1E90FF 24
528446417   Smoothbore247    #228B22 24
510048652   Woody_the_Viking #800080 24
```

Its repeating the first COUNT() for each

Comment: Try `GROUP BY wot_clan_members.account_name` after `WHERE` clause in main query;

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That seems to filter out the repeated names but its got the same value for the total column.

Comment: Decompose your queries and you'll understand what's wrong. Your nested `JOIN` query only returns a `COUNT()` and you don't `JOIN` on any column, thus you are doing an implicit `CROSS JOIN`  which results in a cartesian product. I could arrange your query but I don't really understand what your are trying to `COUNT` so I need more details

Comment: Not possible with single query to fetch 1st row a record group, 2nd row of second, 3rd of 3rd and 4th of 4th;

Comment: I've just added a bit more information to the question.

Comment: I think its beyond my technical ability of mySQL. I'll have to think of another way.

Answer (score 1):

A `join conditition` is needed for the second `join`.

Try this:

```
SELECT wot_clan_members.account_name, wot_info.color, total
FROM wot_info
JOIN wot_clan_members ON wot_clan_members.account_id = wot_info.account_id
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) total, personnelofficer
    FROM wot_info 
    WHERE wot_info.personnelofficer <> '' 
    GROUP BY wot_info.personnelofficer
) as total ON total.personnelofficer = wot_info.personnelofficer
WHERE wot_clan_members.role = 'personnel_officer'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just tried it and it doesn't seem to return any rows.